# Записать список в json

Tags: python, list

Как записать в json три списка a = [1,2,3,4,5] b = [f,w,g,j,q] c = [10,20,30,40,50] , при этом назвать их как A,B,C соответственно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант например так:

```py
import json

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = ["f","w","g","j","q"]
c = [10,20,30,40,50]

l1 = [a, b, c] # Соберем все в список списков
l2 = ["a", "b", "c"] 
res = {l2[i]: l1[i] for i in range(len(l2))} # json готов )

print(json.dumps(res))
```

P.S. От себя поддержу вариант CrazyElf так как он позволяет не городить генераторы списков. Но как вариант написания может быть полезен.

Немного подумав можно через zip

```py
d = {}
for x, y in zip(l2, l1):
    d[x] = y
print(json.dumps(d))
```

Comment: Благодарю но пусть все же будет более подходящий вариант в использовании)

Answer (score 2):

```
import json

a = [1,2,3,4,5] 
b = ['f','w','g','j','q'] 
c = [10,20,30,40,50]
j = {'A': a, 'B': b, 'C': c}
print(json.dumps(j))
```

Вывод:

```
{"A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "B": ["f", "w", "g", "j", "q"], "C": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]}
```